# Autofac configuration for ASP.Net Core 3.1 not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to use Autofac with ASP.Net Core 3.1 but I am getting an exception which does not make sense.

I am getting the following exception:

> Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: 'No accessible constructors were found for the type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeBindingSource'.'

I think the issue might be because of the order of services registered but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. My configuration is as follows:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Startup.cs class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public ILifetimeScope AutofacContainer { get; private set; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<EShopDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

            services.AddSwaggerGen();

            services.AddOptions();
        }

        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
        {
            containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            this.AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "eShop");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

AutofacModule.cs class

```
public class AutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // scan all assemblies in current application domain and resolve them on convention
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the problem with the help of examples code...

The problem for me was in the **AutofacModule.cs** class. I was scanning the assembly incorrectly. Here is the working code.

```
public class AutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // scan all assemblies in current application domain and resolve them on convention
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
    }
```

Autofac has examples of projects in Github and I found out that their documentation was different from their example code. This is the [link](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/tree/master/src/AspNetCore3Example) of the ASP.Net Core 3.1 Example. for anyone who wants to see the configuration.